# How can I share a python module and its variables between uwsgi workers using Django

Tags: python, django, opencv, uwsgi

I am currently working on a Django app that uses a module I created called "stream". This module starts a thread to open a camera with OpenCV and yield frames.

Now that I am trying to run it with nginx and uwsgi I realized that the stream module gets initialized with every new worker. This causes a problem as each worker is attempting to start a new connection with the same camera.

Is there a way to make this stream module globally accessible between workers instead of being initialized by every worker?

(below is a snippet of my views.py)

```
from . import stream


@xframe_options_exempt
@login_required
def stream_log(request) -> StreamingHttpResponse:
    """
    This endpoint requires a logged in user to
    view the logged data for the current stream session. It is
    fed through an iframe into the `view` page
    :param request: http request
    :return: StreamingHttpResponse
    """
    try:
        return StreamingHttpResponse(stream.log_feed())
    except:
        pass


@login_required
@gzip.gzip_page
def camera_stream(request) -> StreamingHttpResponse:
    """
    This endpoint requires a logged in user to
    view the stream feed from the camera. It is
    fed through an iframe into the `view` page
    :param request: http request
    :return: StreamingHttpResponse
    """
    try:
        return StreamingHttpResponse(stream.video_camera.feed(),
                                     content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
    except:
        pass
```

EDIT:

The bot said I wasn't clear enough so I'll add some more details. The streaming workings when running just one Django worker or just using the runserver command unless more than one user connects.

I added a `print("ifname")` to the module `__init__.py` to see if it was being called more than once. In the uwsgi log file we can see that it is

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please review [mre], [ask]